# Firefox add-on builder: is it possible to add a .Panel on navigation toolbar

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm a newbie in **Firefox add-ons development**. I'm developing an `add-on` and able add a button on navigation toolbar. But I need to add a `panel` (size of 125x30) instead of a button. Is it possible? If possible please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible that I know of, though I am also relatively new. You can [create a 125x30 button](http://kendsnyder.com/posts/firefox-extensions-add-button-to-nav-bar) - thanks ken snyder - or you can [create a widget in the Add-On bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/display-a-popup.html). Either of these could open a separate panel, but I don't think you can directly insert a panel into a toolbar with the new SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ok then, is it possible to put `html` code instead of button label?

Comment: If you interested in a pretty in-depth tutorial on toolbars, then there is a super-detailed series of posts over at [borngeek](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/). I really don't know enough to be able to advise you on exactly what you want to do since I don't have a good idea of what you are trying to implement, but Chapter 3 of that tutorial has some really in-depth sample code. Definitely consider working through that to get a good idea of what you can and cannot do with extensions. I've only worked with the JetPack stuff, which is a bit limited.